# Can you apply a CoreImage filter to a video capture session & then a CoreML Object Detection model to that filtered video?

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, core-image, coreml

I am wondering if you are able to apply a CoreImage filter to a video capture session and then apply a CoreML Object Detection model on that filtered video?

I can do each one separately on a pixel buffer, but i am struggling to do both together.

Comment: Can you please describe the data flow in more detail? What's the output of the model? Should the video feed still be shown to the user? If yes, filtered or not? Thanks!

Comment: So I have pre trained a custom ml model which detects objects in a certain homographic view. And so I have implemented that ml model into swift reading the pixels from the pixelbuffer, simailar to this example developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_objects_in_live_capture. But before I recognise an object from the AVCapture I want to use a CIPerspectiveCorrection CIFilter on the CVPixelBuffer to create this "Homographic View" and then detect the objects from this view.

So I was looking for some guidance on how to implement this? The filtered view does need to be shown too.

Comment: Is the output of your model an image?

Comment: You say they both work separately, so perhaps show how you are tying to combine the two. Otherwise, there isn't enough information to even try to guess what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that these are the steps

Create and Train a model On which you are to perform Your Task
Start AVCapture session
In didOutput function of AvcaptureSession you will pass the sampleBuffers in a UIImage
Then CreateReq for MLtask The Result you will get will be in PixelBuffer Format which can be use to make the Output Image for the Video Or the same image can be further use for object detection Task by creating another MLtask

```
 `

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Vision
import VideoToolbox
enum Styles : String, CaseIterable{
case starryBlue
case strong
}
 class ViewController: UIViewController,AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
{
let parentStack = UIStackView()
let imageView = UIImageView()
let modelConfigControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Off","CPU","GPU", "Neural Engine"])
let styleTransferControl = UISegmentedControl(items:   [Styles.starryBlue.rawValue,Styles.strong.rawValue])
var currentModelConfig = 0
var currentStyle = Styles.starryBlue

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    setupUI()
    configureSession()
    
}

func setupUI(){
    view.addSubview(parentStack)
    parentStack.axis = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.vertical
    parentStack.distribution = UIStackView.Distribution.fill
    
    parentStack.addArrangedSubview(styleTransferControl)
    parentStack.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
    parentStack.addArrangedSubview(modelConfigControl)
    
    imageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    
    modelConfigControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    styleTransferControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    
    modelConfigControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(modelConfigChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    styleTransferControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(styleTransferChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
}

@objc func modelConfigChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    currentModelConfig = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
}

@objc func styleTransferChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    currentStyle = Styles.allCases[sender.selectedSegmentIndex]
}


 func configureSession(){
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.medium
    
    // search for available capture devices
    let availableDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices
    
    do {
        if let captureDevice = availableDevices.first {
            captureSession.addInput(try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))
    if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput){
        captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
    }
    
    guard let connection = videoOutput.connection(with: .video) else { return }
    guard connection.isVideoOrientationSupported else { return }
    
    connection.videoOrientation = .portrait
    
    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    
    captureSession.startRunning()
}


 func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    
    if currentModelConfig == 0{
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.imageView.image = CameraUtil.imageFromSampleBuffer(buffer: sampleBuffer)
        })
    }
    else{
        
        let config = MLModelConfiguration()
        switch currentModelConfig {
        case 1:
            config.computeUnits = .cpuOnly
        case 2:
            config.computeUnits = .cpuAndGPU
        default:
            config.computeUnits = .all
        }
        
        var s : MLModel?
        
        switch currentStyle {
        case .starryBlue:
            s = try? StyleTransfer_1.init(configuration: config).model
        case .strong:
            s = try? StyleTransfer_2.init(configuration: config).model
        }
        
        guard let styleModel = s else{return}
        
        guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: styleModel) else { return }
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (finishedRequest, error) in
            guard let results = finishedRequest.results as? [VNPixelBufferObservation] else { return }
            
            guard let observation = results.first else { return }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(pixelBuffer: observation.pixelBuffer)
            })
        }
        
        guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
        try? VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])
    }
}


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    let topMargin = topLayoutGuide.length
    parentStack.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: topMargin, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - topMargin).insetBy(dx: 5, dy: 5)    
} 
}
   extension UIImage {
public convenience init?(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
    var cgImage: CGImage?
    VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, options: nil, imageOut: &cgImage)
    
    if let cgImage = cgImage {
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
 }

    class CameraUtil {
    class func imageFromSampleBuffer(buffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage   {
    let pixelBuffer: CVImageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(buffer)!
    
    let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
    
    let pixelBufferWidth = CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer))
    let pixelBufferHeight = CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer))
    let imageRect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pixelBufferWidth, height: pixelBufferHeight)
    let ciContext = CIContext.init()
    let cgimage = ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, from: imageRect )
    
    let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgimage!)
    return image
}

  }

   `
```